# How to add to ggplot2 plot inside of for loop

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to plot multiple circles of different sizes on a plot using ggplot2's geom_point inside of a for loop. Every time I run it though, it plots all the circles, but all in the location of the last circle instead of in their respective locations as given by the data frame. Below is an example of the code I am running. I'm wondering how I would fix this or if there's a better way to get at what I'm trying to do here.

```
data <- data.frame("x" = c(0, 500, 1000, 1500, 2000),
 "y" = c(1500, 500, 2000, 0, 1000), 
 "size" = c(3, 5, 1.5, 4.2, 2.6)
)

g <- ggplot(data = data, aes(x = x, y = y)) + xlim(0,2000) + ylim(0,2000)
for(i in 1:5) {
  g <- g + geom_point(aes(x=data$x[i],y=data$y[i]), size = data$size[i], pch = 1)
}
print(g)
```

Answer (score 3):

It's pretty rare to need a for-loop for a plot -- ggplot2 will take the whole dataframe and process it all without you needing to manage each row.

```
ggplot(data = data, aes(x = x, y = y, size = size)) + 
  geom_point(pch = 1)
```

Comment: Nice ! I did not know that you could pass the size argument in the `aes` of `ggplot` ;)

Comment: If you take a look at `?geom_point` to get its help page, you'll see a section on aesthetics. You can give it size, shape, and a host of other directions - and any of those can be dynamic based on your data.

Comment: I knew about the definition of group and color in the `aes`. Thanks for the tip ;) I just realized that my answer is completely wrong (not the right size vector). I deleted it. Yours is much better.